# import csv with backslash

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am trying to import a csv file inside mysql using a php page.
I have a problem with \ it being ignored. How can I do to solve it?
I leave the code of the import.php file, thanks in advance.

C:UsersvenicDesktoplinklogo_ariel.png

C:\Users\venic\Desktop\link\logo_ariel.png

Andrea

```
<?php
include_once("db_connect.php");
if(isset($_POST['import_data'])){    
    // validate to check uploaded file is a valid csv file
    $file_mimes = array('text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel', 'text/plain');
    if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name']) && in_array($_FILES['file']['type'],$file_mimes)){
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){   
            $csv_file = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r');           
            //fgetcsv($csv_file);            
            // get data records from csv file
            while(($emp_record = fgetcsv($csv_file)) !== FALSE){
                // Check if employee already exists with same email
                $sql_query = "SELECT emp_id, campo_1a, campo_1b, campo_1a_1, campo_1c, campo_2a, campo_2b, campo_3a, campo_3a_1, campo_3b, campo_3c, campo_4a, campo_5a, campo_5b, campo_6a, campo_7a, campo_7b, campo_8a, campo_8b, campo_9a, campo_9b, campo_10a, campo_10b, campo_10a1, campo_10b1, campo_11a, campo_11b, campo_12a, campo_12b, campo_13a, campo_13b, campo_13c, campo_14, campo_15, campo_16, campo_17, campo_18, campo_19, campo_20, campo_21a, campo_21b, campo_21c1, campo_21c2, campo_21c3, campo_21c4, campo_21d, campo_30a, campo_30b, campo_30c, campo_31, campo_32, campo_33, campo_34, campo_35, campo_35_1, campo_36, campo_37, campo_38, campo_39, campo_39_1, campo_40, campo_41, campo_42, campo_43, quantita_d, quantita_e FROM emp WHERE campo_22 = '".$emp_record[1]."'";
                $resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_query) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
                // if employee already exist then update details otherwise insert new record
                if(mysqli_num_rows($resultset)) {                     
                    $sql_update = "UPDATE emp set campo_1a='".$emp_record[2]."', campo_1b='".$emp_record[3]."', campo_1a_1='".$emp_record[4]."', campo_1c='".$emp_record[5]."', campo_2a='".$emp_record[6]."', campo_2b='".$emp_record[7]."', campo_3a='".$emp_record[8]."', campo_3a_1='".$emp_record[9]."', campo_3b='".$emp_record[10]."', campo_3c='".$emp_record[11]."', campo_3d='".$emp_record[12]."', campo_4a='".$emp_record[13]."', campo_5a='".$emp_record[14]."', campo_5b='".$emp_record[15]."', campo_6a='".$emp_record[16]."', campo_6b='".$emp_record[17]."', campo_7a='".$emp_record[18]."', campo_7b='".$emp_record[19]."', campo_8a='".$emp_record[20]."', campo_8b='".$emp_record[21]."', campo_9a='".$emp_record[22]."', campo_9b='".$emp_record[23]."', campo_10a='".$emp_record[24]."', campo_10b='".$emp_record[25]."', campo_10a1='".$emp_record[26]."', campo_10b1='".$emp_record[27]."', campo_11a='".$emp_record[28]."', campo_11b='".$emp_record[29]."', campo_12a='".$emp_record[30]."', campo_12b='".$emp_record[31]."', campo_13a='".$emp_record[32]."', campo_13b='".$emp_record[33]."', campo_13c='".$emp_record[34]."', campo_14='".$emp_record[35]."', campo_15='".$emp_record[36]."', campo_16='".$emp_record[37]."', campo_17='".$emp_record[38]."', campo_18='".$emp_record[39]."', campo_19='".$emp_record[40]."', campo_20='".$emp_record[41]."', campo_21a='".$emp_record[42]."', campo_21b='".$emp_record[43]."', campo_21c1='".$emp_record[44]."', campo_21c2='".$emp_record[45]."', campo_21c3='".$emp_record[46]."', campo_21c4='".$emp_record[47]."', campo_21d='".$emp_record[48]."', campo_30a='".$emp_record[49]."', campo_30b='".$emp_record[50]."', campo_30c='".$emp_record[51]."', campo_31='".$emp_record[52]."', campo_32='".$emp_record[53]."', campo_33='".$emp_record[54]."', campo_34='".$emp_record[55]."', campo_35='".$emp_record[56]."', campo_35_1='".$emp_record[57]."', campo_36='".$emp_record[58]."', campo_37='".$emp_record[59]."', campo_38='".$emp_record[60]."', campo_39='".$emp_record[61]."', campo_39_1='".$emp_record[62]."', campo_40='".$emp_record[63]."', campo_41='".$emp_record[64]."', campo_42='".$emp_record[65]."', campo_43='".$emp_record[66]."', quantita_d='".$emp_record[67]."', quantita_e='".$emp_record[68]."' WHERE campo_22 = '".$emp_record[1]."'";
                    mysqli_query($conn, $sql_update) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
                } else{
                    $mysql_insert = "INSERT INTO emp (campo_22, campo_1a,  campo_1a_1, campo_1b, campo_1c, campo_2a, campo_2b, campo_3a, campo_3a_1, campo_3b, campo_3c, campo_3d, campo_4a, campo_5a, campo_5b, campo_6a, campo_6b, campo_7a, campo_7b, campo_8a, campo_8b, campo_9a, campo_9b, campo_10a, campo_10b, campo_10a1, campo_10b1, campo_11a, campo_11b, campo_12a, campo_12b, campo_13a, campo_13b, campo_13c, campo_14, campo_15, campo_16, campo_17, campo_18, campo_19, campo_20, campo_21a, campo_21b, campo_21c1, campo_21c2, campo_21c3, campo_21c4, campo_21d, campo_30a, campo_30b, campo_30c, campo_31, campo_32, campo_33, campo_34, campo_35, campo_35_1, campo_36, campo_37, campo_38, campo_39, campo_39_1, campo_40, campo_41, campo_42, campo_43, quantita_d, quantita_e)VALUES('".$emp_record[1]."', '".$emp_record[2]."', '".$emp_record[3]."', '".$emp_record[4]."', '".$emp_record[5]."', '".$emp_record[6]."', '".$emp_record[7]."', '".$emp_record[8]."', '".$emp_record[9]."', '".$emp_record[10]."', '".$emp_record[11]."', '".$emp_record[12]."', '".$emp_record[13]."', '".$emp_record[14]."', '".$emp_record[15]."', '".$emp_record[16]."', '".$emp_record[17]."', '".$emp_record[18]."', '".$emp_record[19]."', '".$emp_record[20]."', '".$emp_record[21]."', '".$emp_record[22]."', '".$emp_record[23]."', '".$emp_record[24]."', '".$emp_record[25]."', '".$emp_record[26]."', '".$emp_record[27]."', '".$emp_record[28]."', '".$emp_record[29]."', '".$emp_record[30]."', '".$emp_record[31]."', '".$emp_record[32]."', '".$emp_record[33]."', '".$emp_record[34]."', '".$emp_record[35]."', '".$emp_record[36]."', '".$emp_record[37]."', '".$emp_record[38]."', '".$emp_record[39]."', '".$emp_record[40]."', '".$emp_record[41]."', '".$emp_record[42]."', '".$emp_record[43]."', '".$emp_record[44]."', '".$emp_record[45]."', '".$emp_record[46]."', '".$emp_record[47]."', '".$emp_record[48]."', '".$emp_record[49]."', '".$emp_record[50]."', '".$emp_record[51]."', '".$emp_record[52]."', '".$emp_record[53]."', '".$emp_record[54]."', '".$emp_record[55]."', '".$emp_record[56]."', '".$emp_record[57]."', '".$emp_record[58]."', '".$emp_record[59]."', '".$emp_record[60]."', '".$emp_record[61]."', '".$emp_record[62]."', '".$emp_record[63]."', '".$emp_record[64]."', '".$emp_record[65]."', '".$emp_record[66]."', '".$emp_record[67]."', '".$emp_record[68]."')";
                    mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_insert) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
                }
            }            
            fclose($csv_file);
            $import_status = '?import_status=success';
        } else {
            $import_status = '?import_status=error';
        }
    } else {
        $import_status = '?import_status=invalid_file';
    }
}
header("Location: index.php".$import_status);
?>
```

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!
This will also remove the unescaped character issue like a `'` in a text string like `O'Neal'.

Comment: You dont need to fetch 100's of columns in a select if all you want to do is check if a row with a specific key exists. A simple `SELECT COUNT(campo_22) as cnt FROM emp WHERE campo_22 = ?"` Then check the resultset for `cnt` = 1 or 0

Comment: Where is the issue with backslashes? I have a feeling if you use a Prepared and parameterized query, the issue would disappear

Comment: @RiggsFolly I understand what you want to tell me, could you explain more? Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Backslashesin your CSV file are being ignored when you try to import it into MySQL using PHP. This is likely due to the fact that backslashes are used as escape characters in PHP strings, and therefore they are being interpreted as such.

```
   // get data records from csv file
   while(($emp_record = fgetcsv($csv_file)) !== FALSE){
      // Escape backslashes in the CSV data
      foreach ($emp_record as &$value) {
        $value = addslashes($value);
      }
   // Check if employee already exists with same email
```

Comment: For those that care, this is NOT a good solution

Comment: If you PREPARE the Queries, then this will not be a problem and you need do no more. You should be prepareing the queries anyway for protection against SQL Injection

Comment: @RiggsFolly Can you give me some more information that I try to understand? Thank you for the availability

Answer (score 0):

You should prepare a parameterised query and then bind values to that query.

This has a number of benefits,

1. you protect from SQL Injection.
2. You get odd data like names `Peter O'Toole` and `C:\` handled safely automatically.
3. You can prepare a query ONCE and then reuse it in a loop with different data applied each time it is executed. This means you reduce the number of trips to and from the server and the amount of effort the server has to apply to running your queries

```
<?php
include_once("db_connect.php");

if(isset($_POST['import_data'])){    
    // validate to check uploaded file is a valid csv file
    $file_mimes = array('text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel', 'text/plain');
    if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name']) && in_array($_FILES['file']['type'],$file_mimes)){
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){   
            $csv_file = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r');           

            // prepare the 2 statements, only once, run them multiple times
            // this reduces round trips to the server and makes everything a bit faster

            $sql = "UPDATE emp 
                        set campo_1a = ?, campo_1b= ?, campo_1a_1= ?, campo_1c = ?, 
                            campo_2a = ?, campo_2b = ?, campo_3a = ?, campo_3a_1 = ?, 
                            campo_3b = ?, campo_3c = ?, campo_3d = ?, campo_4a = ?, 
                            campo_5a = ?, campo_5b = ?, campo_6a = ?, campo_6b = ?, 
                            campo_7a = ?, campo_7b = ?, campo_8a = ?, campo_8b = ?, 
                            campo_9a = ?, campo_9b = ?, campo_10a = ?, campo_10b = ?, 
                            campo_10a1 = ?, campo_10b1 = ?, campo_11a = ?, campo_11b = ?, 
                            campo_12a = ?, campo_12b = ?, campo_13a = ?, campo_13b = ?, 
                            campo_13c = ?, campo_14 = ?, campo_15 = ?, campo_16 = ?, 
                            campo_17 = ?, campo_18 = ?, campo_19 = ?, campo_20 = ?, 
                            campo_21a = ?, campo_21b = ?, campo_21c1 = ?, campo_21c2= ?, 
                            campo_21c3 = ?, campo_21c4 = ?, campo_21d = ?, campo_30a = ?, 
                            campo_30b= ?, campo_30c = ?, campo_31 = ?, campo_32= ?, 
                            campo_33 = ?, campo_34 = ?, campo_35 = ?, campo_35_1 = ?, 
                            campo_36 = ?, campo_37 = ?, campo_38 = ?, campo_39 = ?, 
                            campo_39_1 = ?, campo_40 = ?, campo_41 = ?, campo_42= ?, 
                            campo_43 = ?, quantita_d = ?, quantita_e = ?
                    WHERE campo_22 = ?";
            $update_stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
            
            $sql = "INSERT INTO emp 
                    (campo_22, campo_1a,  campo_1a_1, campo_1b, campo_1c, campo_2a, 
                    campo_2b, campo_3a, campo_3a_1, campo_3b, campo_3c, campo_3d, campo_4a, 
                    campo_5a, campo_5b, campo_6a, campo_6b, campo_7a, campo_7b, campo_8a, 
                    campo_8b, campo_9a, campo_9b, campo_10a, campo_10b, campo_10a1, campo_10b1, 
                    campo_11a, campo_11b, campo_12a, campo_12b, campo_13a, campo_13b, campo_13c, 
                    campo_14, campo_15, campo_16, campo_17, campo_18, campo_19, campo_20, 
                    campo_21a, campo_21b, campo_21c1, campo_21c2, campo_21c3, campo_21c4, 
                    campo_21d, campo_30a, campo_30b, campo_30c, campo_31, campo_32, campo_33, 
                    campo_34, campo_35, campo_35_1, campo_36, campo_37, campo_38, campo_39, 
                    campo_39_1, campo_40, campo_41, campo_42, campo_43, quantita_d, quantita_e)
                VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,
                        ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

            $insert_stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);


            while(($emp_record = fgetcsv($csv_file)) !== FALSE){
                // Check if employee already exists with same email
                $sql = "SELECT COUNT(campo_22) as cnt FROM emp WHERE campo_22 = ?";
                $check = $conn->prepare($sql);
                $check->bind_param('s', $emp_record[1]);
                $check->execute();
                $cnt = $check->get_result()->fetch_row()[0];
                
                // if employee already exist then update details otherwise insert new record
                if($cnt = 1) {  
                    // UPDATE existng row 67 columns
                    $update_stmt->bind_param('sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss',
                                $emp_record[2], $emp_record[3], $emp_record[4], $emp_record[5], 
                                $emp_record[6], $emp_record[7], $emp_record[8], $emp_record[9], 
                                $emp_record[10], $emp_record[11], $emp_record[12], $emp_record[13], 
                                $emp_record[14], $emp_record[15], $emp_record[16], $emp_record[17], 
                                $emp_record[18], $emp_record[19], $emp_record[20], $emp_record[21], 
                                $emp_record[22], $emp_record[23], $emp_record[24], $emp_record[25], 
                                $emp_record[26], $emp_record[27], $emp_record[28], $emp_record[29], 
                                $emp_record[30], $emp_record[31], $emp_record[32], $emp_record[33], 
                                $emp_record[34], $emp_record[35], $emp_record[36], $emp_record[37], 
                                $emp_record[38], $emp_record[39], $emp_record[40], $emp_record[41], 
                                $emp_record[42], $emp_record[43], $emp_record[44], $emp_record[45], 
                                $emp_record[46], $emp_record[47], $emp_record[48], $emp_record[49], 
                                $emp_record[50], $emp_record[51], $emp_record[52], $emp_record[53],
                                $emp_record[54], $emp_record[55], $emp_record[56], $emp_record[57], 
                                $emp_record[58], $emp_record[59], $emp_record[60], $emp_record[61], 
                                $emp_record[62], $emp_record[63], $emp_record[64], $emp_record[65], 
                                $emp_record[66], $emp_record[67], $emp_record[68], $emp_record[1]";
                    $update_stmt->execute();
                    
                } else{
                    $insert_stmt->bind_param('sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss',
                                $emp_record[1],
                                $emp_record[2], $emp_record[3], $emp_record[4], $emp_record[5], 
                                $emp_record[6], $emp_record[7], $emp_record[8], $emp_record[9], 
                                $emp_record[10], $emp_record[11], $emp_record[12], $emp_record[13], 
                                $emp_record[14], $emp_record[15], $emp_record[16], $emp_record[17], 
                                $emp_record[18], $emp_record[19], $emp_record[20], $emp_record[21], 
                                $emp_record[22], $emp_record[23], $emp_record[24], $emp_record[25], 
                                $emp_record[26], $emp_record[27], $emp_record[28], $emp_record[29], 
                                $emp_record[30], $emp_record[31], $emp_record[32], $emp_record[33], 
                                $emp_record[34], $emp_record[35], $emp_record[36], $emp_record[37], 
                                $emp_record[38], $emp_record[39], $emp_record[40], $emp_record[41], 
                                $emp_record[42], $emp_record[43], $emp_record[44], $emp_record[45], 
                                $emp_record[46], $emp_record[47], $emp_record[48], $emp_record[49], 
                                $emp_record[50], $emp_record[51], $emp_record[52], $emp_record[53],
                                $emp_record[54], $emp_record[55], $emp_record[56], $emp_record[57], 
                                $emp_record[58], $emp_record[59], $emp_record[60], $emp_record[61], 
                                $emp_record[62], $emp_record[63], $emp_record[64], $emp_record[65], 
                                $emp_record[66], $emp_record[67], $emp_record[68]";                  
                 $insert_stmt->execute();
                }
                
            }            
            fclose($csv_file);
            $import_status = '?import_status=success';
        } else {
            $import_status = '?import_status=error';
        }
    } else {
        $import_status = '?import_status=invalid_file';
    }
}
header("Location: index.php".$import_status);
```

Comment: Hi, I am just starting out and trying to learn on my own and I always thank you people in the community for the help.
I tried adding your code the moment I load the csv it gives me error 500

Comment: ANy more details in the error log

Comment: On the editor I get "syntax error unexpected T_IF" in line 61

Comment: [02-Mar-2023 14:19:12 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected token "if" in /home/u147675664/domains/atena.net/public_html/unical/import.php on line 61

Comment: Heavans above::: Missing semi colon on this line `$cnt = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_row()[0];`

Comment: [03-Mar-2023 08:40:31 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_result() on bool in /home/u147675664/domains/atena.net/public_html/unical/import.php:58
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/u147675664/domains/atena.net/public_html/unical/import.php on line 58

Comment: Sorry, typo : Change line to `$cnt = $check->get_result()->fetch_row()[0];`